# Combine result from multiple Monos when number is not fixed?

Tags: project-reactor

How to combine a list of Monos to a single Mono. Right now I am calling let say 5 services and two of the calls succeeded but three of them might fail.I want to have a track of all those failed and which all succeeded. I tried using Mono.zipdelayError but its not working that way. Whenever error comes it comes to my resource exception handler.

Just for information , I have exposed a rest API which will internally call a number of services which are returning monos and I have to combine result of those calls into one Mono.

```
Mono<String> error = Mono.error(new RuntimeException());

    error.onErrorResume(throwable-> Mono.just("hell0"));

    Mono<String> test = Mono.just("test");
    Mono<String> test1 = Mono.just("test1");
    Mono<String> test2 = Mono.just("test2");

    List<Mono<String>> monolist = new ArrayList<>();
    monolist.add(test);
    monolist.add(test1);
    monolist.add(test2);
    monolist.add(error);
     Mono<Long> zipDelayError = Mono.zipDelayError(monolist, arrayObj -> Arrays.stream(arrayObj).count());

    System.out.println(zipDelayError.block());
```

It is breaking right now .

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the Project reactor javadoc for `Mono`](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html), `Mono.zip` will:

> Aggregate given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item, aggregating their values according to the provided combinator function. An error or empty completion of any source will cause other sources to be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete, respectively.

This means that for the following example:

```
Mono<User> user = ...
Mono<Account> account = ...
Mono<Info> info = ...
Mono<Tuple3<User, Account, Info>> tuple = Mono.zip(user, account, info);
```

You either get a:

- `Tuple` containing all 3 values if everything went fine
- an empty `Mono` if one of them completed as empty
- an error signal if one of them failed

In the last 2 cases, others are cancelled right away, which means that you won't know if you'd get an error or a valid element from them if things were to continue. There's no way to get a hold of values that were already resolved when things failed.

There are many ways to have more fine grained behavior here.

You can, on the zipped `Mono` or any upstream one, add `doOnError` operators to log information if things fail, or even `onErrorResume` to use fallback operations; you can also chain `retry` operators to describe how/when it should retry in case of failures.

Comment: This use case which I am trying to solve is that from my list of Monos some monos are bound to fail. In case there is anything currently present in reactor library please do let me know.

Comment: Edited my question.